# .NET Core : IFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents recursive not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I would like to scan a directory ("C:/test") and get all files .pdf recursively
I create a provider like this :

```
IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider("C:/test"); // using config in my code and also tried with "C:/test/"
```

I placed some pdf in directories and subdirectories

There's a file with this path : C:/test/pdf59.pdf
Another with C:/test/testComplexe/pdf59.pdf

Where I try these lines, they all return "NotFoundDirectoryException" :

```
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"**")
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"*")
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"*.*")
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"**.*")    
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"pdf59.pdf")
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"*.pdf")
```

Exception this line :

```
provider.getDirectoryContents(@"testComplexe")
```

How could i query these recursive directories and files ? Thank you

Comment: Could you use `DirectoryInfo` class and then use EnumerateFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)?

Comment: Been chasing this rabbit hole all day as well. Turns out, if you look at the implementation for `PhysicalFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(string)` it returns a `NotFoundDirectoryContents` if the path is either a root directory or has invalid path characters (excluding path separators), so the globbing characters are not allowed. Frustrating because the docs says globbing not allowed for `GetFileInfo`, sorta implying _is_ allowed for `GetDirectoryContents`. Shame because `FileSystemGlobbing.Matcher` does recursive glob matching, but has non compatible file and directory types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own recursive function.

```
var files = new List<IFileInfo>();
GetFiles("C:/Tests", files);

private void GetFiles(string path, ICollection<IFileInfo> files)
{
    IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path);

    var contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents("");

    foreach (var content in contents)
    {
        if (!content.IsDirectory && content.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            files.Add(content);
        }
        else
        {
            GetFiles(content.PhysicalPath, files);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will create a new `PhysicalFileProvider` for each directory. You should instead call `GetDirectoryContents` on your existing provider instance with the (aggregated) path of the subdirectory.

Answer (score 3):

For my future self (and others) to copy-paste...

```
public static class Demo
{
    public static void FindPdfs()
    {
        var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider("c:\\temp");
        var pdfs = new List<IFileInfo>();

        provider.FindFiles(
            directory: "/",
            match: file => file.Name.EndsWith(".pdf"),
            process: pdfs.Add,
            recursive: true);

        foreach (var pdf in pdfs)
        {
            using (var stream = pdf.CreateReadStream())
            {
                // etc...
            }
        }

    }
}

public static class FileProviderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches for files matching some <paramref name="match"/>, and invokes <paramref name="process"/> on them.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="provider">File provider</param>
    /// <param name="directory">parent directory for the search, a relative path, leading slashes are ignored,
    /// use "" or "/" for starting at the root of <paramref name="provider"/></param>
    /// <param name="match">the match predicate, if this returns true the file is passed to <paramref name="process"/></param>
    /// <param name="process">this action is invoked on <paramref name="match"/>ing files </param>
    /// <param name="recursive">if true directories a</param>
    /// <returns>the number of files <paramref name="match"/>ed and <paramref name="process"/>ed</returns>
    public static int FindFiles(this IFileProvider provider, string directory, Predicate<IFileInfo> match, Action<IFileInfo> process, bool recursive = false)
    {
        var dirsToSearch = new Stack<string>();
        dirsToSearch.Push(directory);
        var count = 0;
        while (dirsToSearch.Count > 0)
        {
            var dir = dirsToSearch.Pop();
            foreach (var file in provider.GetDirectoryContents(dir))
            {
                if (file.IsDirectory)
                {
                    if (!recursive)
                        continue;

                    var relPath = Path.Join(dir, file.Name);
                    dirsToSearch.Push(relPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!match(file))
                        continue;

                    process(file);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest version if you just want a list of `IFileInfo` objects. It uses an extension method. Assumes you already have a IFileProvider, such as one that has been injected.

```
var files = FileProvider.GetRecursiveFiles("/images").ToArray();
```

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public static class FileProviderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IFileInfo> GetRecursiveFiles(this IFileProvider fileProvider, string path, bool includeDirectories = true)
    {
        var directoryContents = fileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(path);
        foreach (var file in directoryContents)
        {
            if (file.IsDirectory)
            {
                if (includeDirectories)
                {
                    yield return file;
                }

                // recursively call GetFiles and return each one
                // file.Name is the directory name alone (eg. images)
                foreach (var f in fileProvider.GetRecursiveFiles(Path.Combine(path, file.Name), includeDirectories))
                {
                    yield return f;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // return file
                yield return file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note if  the order of files is important to you you may need to switch around the order of some of these yields.

Answer (score -1):

To get the content of your root folder ("*C:/test/*"), use the provider this way :

```
var contents = provider.getDirectoryContents("")
```

Then, you have to enumerate results in `contents`, and do what ever you want with each one.

Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Yes, but this is not recursive mode, and won't look at subdirectories